# Angular 2 bootstrap use with template

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I am having a small component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "tomato-timer",
  templateUrl: './tomato-timer.html'
})
export class TomatoTimerComponent {
  onCountdownCompleted(): void{
    alert('Time UP!');
  }
}
```

With a template:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <img src="../assets/img/tomato.png" alt="Tomato">
    <countdown
        [seconds] = "25"
        (complete) = "onCountdownCompleted()"
        #counter>
    </countdown>
    <p>

        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger"

                 (click)="counter.seconds = 25">
            Reset countdown to 25 seconds
        </button>
    </p>
    <p *ngIf="counter.seconds < 10">
        Beware! Only
        <strong>{{ counter.seconds }} seconds</strong>
        left.
    </p>
</div>
```

I am using ng-bootstrap but I don't understand how to make this stupid button make look as btn-danger though I have specified everything in the template.Frankly speaking,Angular is awful

Here is module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TomatoTimerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [TomatoTimerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: did you added `bootstrap.css` on your page? that will suffice `btn-danger` CSS rule on button

Comment: Yes I did. See my answer

Comment: how have you added bootstrap to your project can you show , i think you are using cli

Comment: npm install --save bootstrap. the same for ng-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add such import to styles.css:

```
@import url('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```